# Text in dropdown menu ignoring z-index in IE7

Tags: css, z-index, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7

The problem:
The sub menu text in 'tier 2' sits in front of the sub menu text in 'tier 3'. Oddly, the ul does not, just the text.

http://i41.tinypic.com/ajuhz6.jpg

I am aware that there is a bug in IE7 to do with z-index.
Usually in this situation I would fix the issue in IE7 by giving one of the outer containers a higher z-index than the children.

If anyone is reading this because they have the same issue I recommend trying this first:-
http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/

Nothing has worked for me so far and I have tried many solutions posted on Stack Overflow and elsewhere.

Here is my code...
I have a simple tiered drop down menu with the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="wdk_header-container">

<div>...</div>

<div class="wdk_menu-container">

    <ul class="wdk_menu-ul wdk_tier_1">
        <li class="wdk_menu-item wdk_level_1">

            <a href="/"><span>Menu Text</span></a>

            <ul class="wdk_sub_menu wdk_tier_2">
                <li class="wdk_menu-item wdk_level_2">

                    <a href="/"><span>Menu Text</span></a>

                    <ul class="wdk_sub_menu wdk_tier_3">
                        <li class="wdk_menu-item wdk_level_3">

                            <a href="/"><span>Menu Text</span></a>

                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
            </ul>

        </li>
    </ul>

</div>


<div>...</div>
<div>...</div>


</div>
```

I cannot edit the structure of the menu. As you can see, there are other divs within the  outter most containter.

I use the following jQuery to show and hide the menu tiers:

```
$(function(){

$("ul.wdk_menu-ul li").hover(function(){

    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'visible');

}, function(){

    $('ul:first',this).css('visibility', 'hidden');

});

});
```

The following CSS works fine in Firefox and Chrome but not in IE7.

```
<style>

/* All Menu Items */
.wdk_menu-container ul {
    list-style: none; display: inline;
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}
.wdk_menu-container ul li {
    float: left; height: 33px; position: relative; display: block;
}
.wdk_menu-container ul li a {
    display: block; height: 100%;
}

/* Sub Menu */
ul.wdk_sub_menu.wdk_tier_2 {
    float: left; z-index: 5; position: absolute;
}

ul.wdk_sub_menu.wdk_tier_2 a {
    line-height: 16px; padding: 6px 10px;
}

.wdk_menu-container ul.wdk_sub_menu.wdk_tier_2 li a span {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Sub Sub Menu */
ul.wdk_sub_menu.wdk_tier_3 {
    float: left; z-index: 6; position: absolute; left: 34px;
}

</style>
```

I will be creating a separate stylesheet for IE7. Any suggestions welcome, its driving me insane. If you need more information please ask!
Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention, I do at least know that in IE7 I have had to add the following CSS to get the menu to appear above any of the content.

    .wdk_menu-container { position: relative; z-index: 2; }

Answer (score 0):

You have this problem because you have position:absolute applied to the elements together with z-index. This doesn't work in IE7. You need to use position:relative instead (and find another way to smartly position your submenus). http://www.shawnpreisz.com/css/z-index-internet-explorer-7-ie7

Comment: I managed to come up with a sort of fix before seeing George Katsanos' answer. Reading your answer, everything seems a lot clearer, so thanks. 

However, I fixed it by removing the `position: relative` from the parent `li` of each sub-menu.

Despite the parent not have `position: relative`, the `position: absolute` sub menus still seem to position nicely, to the left, underneath their respective parent `li`.

I thought this was impossible - because don't `absolute: positions` elements position themselves within the nearest `position: relative` parent. Perhaps this is due to the `float: left`?